# How to split stdout to go to several output files?

Tags: text-processing

Say, I have a command `command` which prints huge number of lines to stdout:

```
line1
line2
.....
lineN
```

I want to save the output to disk, but not as a single file, but as a sequence of files each having 1000 lines of stdout:

```
file0001.txt:
-------------
line1
....
line1000

file0002.txt:
-------------
line1001
....
line2000

etc
```

I've tried to google the answer, but every time google points me to `tee` command, which is useless in this situation. Probably, I'm entering wrong queries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Once you are done saving the file, you could always `split` the file into file pieces or multiple files based on the number of lines.

`split -l 1000 output_file`

or even better just try

`command | split -l 1000 -`

This will split the output stream into files with each 1000 lines (default is 1000 lines without -l option).

The below command will give you additional flexibility to put or enforce a prefix to the filename that will be generated when the output is generated and splitted to store into the file.

`command | split -l 1000 - small-`

Comment: I got confused, so for others, its `split [arguments...] [input e.g. "-" for stdin] [output_prefix]`, for example: `tar -c somedir | split --byes 100MB --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=3 - somedir.tar.part-` would output a bunch of 100MB files named `somedir.tar.part-000`, 001, 002 ans so on.

Comment: @ThorSummoner I suppose it should be `--bytes`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bash script `lines.bash`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=0
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  printf -v filename "%04d.txt" "$((a++/1000))"
  echo "$line" >> $filename
done
```

and use it as:

`cat long_file.txt | bash lines.bash`

The only problem I noticed is with `*` sign in `long_file.txt` (somebody could correct it).

Comment: Set the `IFS` to empty string to avoid word splitting on `read`. Use `-r` to disable backslash escaping on `read`. Remove `-e` to avoid backslash escaping on `echo`. Use quoting to avoid word splitting on `echo`. Use `-v` in `bash` since 4.0 to avoid starting a sub-process. Use post-incrementing as your current code will put in the first file only 999 lines. `a=0; while IFS='' read -r line; do printf -v filename "%04d.txt" $((a++/1000)); echo "$line" >> "$filename"; done`

Comment: @manatwork Thank you. Only my `printf` does not have `-v` switch. (`bash 4.2.10`). At least it's not in manpage of `printf`

Comment: `man printf` documents /usr/bin/printf, that could never in life set an environment variable. See `help printf` for the `printf` shell built-in's documentation.

Comment: @manatwork OK. There seems to be syntax error in the `++/` part yet.

Comment: One more thing: there is no need to use sigil inside arithmetic evaluation, unless you need parameter expansion explicitly. In arithmetic expansion the variables are evaluated anyway.

Comment: No need to do `IFS=''`, you can just do `IFS=`.

Comment: @ChrisDown one does not simply defy shellcheck :p