# How can I split command stdout into sections, one for each file?

Tags: printing, stdout, split

When a Linux command gets multiple files as input. Is there any command/trick to split command's `stdout` into sections. One for each file? So, it becomes visually clear which lines belong to which file?

For example, when commands such as `cat`, `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, `tail`, get multiple files as input. Generally, they print their results continuously on `stdout`, But I want to split the result into sections. One for each of the input files

I do NOT want to split the result into files, or split it by the number of lines as it is asked in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26175/how-to-split-stdout-to-go-to-several-output-files).
The closest thing that I found to it is using `find -print -exec command` as it is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651315/how-do-you-output-the-filename-in-find-command-while-using-exec). But still not quite what I wanted.

Assuming that my command works on `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`, as input, and prints the following:

```
line1 of file1
line2 of file1
line3 of file1
line1 of file2
line2 of file2
line3 of file2
line1 of file3
line2 of file3
line3 of file3
```

I want the output to be formatted something similar to the following, so when I observed what I was looking for in a file, I can jump to the next file:

```
>>> file1 <<<
line1 of file1
line2 of file1
line3 of file1

----------------
>>> file2 <<<
line1 of file2
line2 of file2
line3 of file2

----------------
>>> file3 <<<
line1 of file3
line2 of file3
line3 of file3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a loop: `for f in "file1 file2 file"; do echo ">>> $f <<<"; your_command $f; done`

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/questions/172284/linux-cat-with-separators-among-files

Comment: Are you asking how you put banners between parts of the output?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
Yes. Banner, as well as the header. Or anything that visually divides the results of different files, just like the way that "head" command does.

Comment: I updated this title for you. But i recommend that you edit the question. Work of the grammar and clarity. I got near to the end, when I suddenly realised what you were asking. It was like a complete about turn. You led me one way, then bang. You told me that it was about something else. You are not sending them to different places.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for the tip. I tried to make it more clear. But, keep in mind that English is not my native language.

Comment: You English writing is good. Better than many natives. If we think clearly, and write at our own level, then everything is good. I could not even guess that you are non-native English writer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the ordering of the lines other than having them sorted by file, you can do this with sort, by prepending each line with the id eg.

```
file1: line1
file2: line1
file1: line2
```

Then you can pipe the result through sort:

```
$ ( process-file1 & process-file2 & ); wait | sort
file1: line1
file1: line2
file2: line1
```

You can of course also add line numbers with this approach - then simply use "sort -n".

To process it into the exact format you want, you can construct a script with awk to strip the front part and turn it into a heading.

Comment: Granted. And the current form of the title is better still.