# Use output of cat with split command and specified output directory

Tags: pipe, cat, split

I'm trying to split a long csv into files of 500 lines each.  I want the output files in a specific directory, and I want to leave off the first line of the csv.

I can use `split` and leave off the first line of the csv by piping the output of `cat`:

`cat file.csv | tail -n +2 | split -l 500`

And I can specify the output directory like so:

`split -l 500 file.csv /mnt/outdir`

But when I try something like this:

`cat file.csv | tail -n +2 | split -l 500 /mnt/outdir`

It thinks that `/mnt/outdir` is the file I am trying to split and tells me `split: /mnt/outdir: Is a directory`.

So how to I somehow pipe output into the `split` command, while specifying an output directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split stdout to go to several output files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26175/how-to-split-stdout-to-go-to-several-output-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-` as the input filename.  e.g.

```
cat file.csv | tail -n +2 | split -l 500 - /mnt/outdir
```

but there's no need for `cat` here.

```
tail -n +2 file.csv | split -l 500 - /mnt/outdir
```

Alternatively, use `/dev/stdin`:

```
tail -n +2 file.csv | split -l 500 /dev/stdin /mnt/outdir
```

or [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
split -l 500 <(tail -n +2 file.csv) /mnt/outdir
```

From `man split` (GNU version):

> `split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Output  pieces of FILE to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000
> lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.
>
> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

You can see from the way that's written `[FILE [PREFIX]]` that if you use a PREFIX, you **must** supply an input filename.  If FILE & PREFIX were both optional and **independent of each other**, it would be written as `[FILE] [PREFIX]`.